# Angular, Protractor automated test locator doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular

I have an angular web application that has some difficult elements to operate. This is a check box that I have to check in my tests:

```
`
<div class="row form-group approval_label">  
<div class="col col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">  
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">  
<input class="custom-control-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" 
formcontrolname="dataProtection" id="date-personale" name="dataProtection" 
tabindex="5" type="checkbox" ng-reflect-name="dataProtection">  
<label class="custom-control-label auto-label" for="date-personale">  
::before  
Am citit si am inteles informarea privind   
::after  
<a> protectia datelor cu caracter personal.</a>  
</label>  
</div>  
</div>  
</div>>  
`
```

Tried to use: 
    `element(by.id('date-personale'))`, 
    `element(by.css("input [class='custom-control-input ng-dirty ng-touched ng-invalid']"))`

But unfortunately I had no luck.
Does anyone has an idea how to locate this element?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
element(by.css('input[type=checkbox].custom-control-input')
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work: Failures:
   Failed: unknown error: Element <input class="custom-control-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" formcontrolname="dataProtection" id="date-personale" name="dataProtection" tabindex="5" type="checkbox" ng-reflect-name="dataProtection"> is not clickable at point (164, 593). Other element would receive the click: <span id="idDatePersonale">...</span>

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I ended up using xpath even if you must avoid it all the time sometimes is the only solution. :)